# Reading text from flat file into variables

Tags: linux, bash

I have some data stored in a flat file, similar to the data which is shown below. I need to be able to extract the data into variables, such as the variable AGE being equal to 24 and the variable user being equal to user01. I also need to be able to tell which database the data is for, such as db[0] and db[1] and so on.

```
db[0].age="24"
db[0].user="user01"
db[0].password="pasword01"
db[0].office="usa office 1"

db[1].age="44"
db[1].userID="user01"
db[1].userPW="password02"
db[1].office="uk office 2"
```

What I've done so far is to use awk to search for all instances of age and extract the number is the square brackets into an array.

```
databaseCount=($(awk '/'"age"'/' flatFile | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1))
```

I was then thinking using a similar awk to extract the text found in the brackets and put that data into an array.

```
age=($(awk '/'"dbUserAlias"'/' flatFile | cut -d\" -f2))
```

I was then planning on using the databaseCount to find the data for weach array, so I would know that the data found in element 0 of the age array is for database 0 and the data found in element 1 is ofr database 1.

The problem that I'm having is that some of the text found between the speech marks has spaces.

```
echo ${office[0]}
```

Would return "uk" instead of "uk office 2".

Does anyone know how to fix this, or if there is a better way to extract the data?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an existing bash script that needs this data? Or are you just trying to process this for some, as yet, unwritten script? If the latter then just do it all in awk directly. That input is practically valid awk already in fact (and could be manipulated into valid awk if desired or parsed by awk which might be "safer"). Trying to chop this up into shell arrays piecemeal is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you access the array in that way you should encapsulate your elements in double quotes, replace your code with the following:

```
age=($(printf "\"$(awk '/'"dbUserAlias"'/' flatFile | cut -d\" -f2)\""))
```

Answer (score 0):

When the flatFile was formatted like

```
age="24"
```

you could have sourced that file.
When you ignore the `db[n]`, you can use

```
. <(cut -d"." -f2- flatFile)
```

Now we want to split up the file for each db and process the lines for each db:

```
for db in {0..5}; do
   sourcelines=$(grep "^db\[${db}\]" flatFile)
   if [[ -n "${sourcelines}" ]]; then
      echo "Database db[${db}]"
      . <(cut -d"." -f2- <<< "${sourcelines}" )
      # show the variables that have been set
      set | grep -E "^age=|^userID=|^userPW=|^office=" | sort
   fi
done
```

When you want to use different variables for different databases, you need a small change:

```
for db in {0..5}; do
   sourcelines=$(grep "^db\[${db}\]" flatFile)
   if [[ -n "${sourcelines}" ]]; then
      echo "Database db[${db}]"
      . <(echo -e "${sourcelines}" | tr "\[\]\." "_")
      # show the variables that have been set
      set | grep -E "^db_${db}_" | sort
   fi
done
```